# Mysteriously popped up "are"

Tags: sentence-construction

"For what case are lightning and 12?"

Should I omit "are" or keep it in this sentence? I wrote it intuitively but don't know why

Comment: What is it supposed to mean; what is the question asking? Either with or without the ‘are’ it makes little sense, at least to me. Could you elaborate on the meaning and/or context?

Comment: @Fivesideddice One guy was explainig why he made a tattoo: "I tattooed myself in case I ever forget how to quit vim". I spotted lightning and number 12 next to it, so asked him about those

Comment: Ah, a very niche case. Presumably people are downvoting because they just think it’s bad english; pay no mind to them.

Comment: "So what are _lightning_ and _12_ in case of?" would be a more natural way to ask.

Comment: Or with less modification: "For what case is the lightning and the 12?" but probably better to swap 'situation' for 'case'. You can use 'the' in this case, as both are now objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the meaning from your further comments, but I don’t think it’s too idiomatic. When someone refers to something being “in case” of something, it’s not particularly idiomatic to then pursue a conversation about “cases”.

I’d probably say something as simple as:

> What about the lightning and the twelve? (What are they for?)

The bracketed phrase is optional.

Or:

> What do the lightning and the twelve mean?

The latter would be more likely said if they are clearly part of the same tattoo.

I suppose I might also say something like:

> Are the lightning and the twelve in case of anything?

Note that I’m replying with “in case” and not asking about “cases” (perhaps a subtle difference but one that makes the phrase idiomatic).

Aside from this, in your original phrasing, “are” would definitely be necessary.